# prevent prompt when open word document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, word, office

I've sharepoint 2010 and a document library containing word or excel.
I've office suite 2010.

When i want to open a word from my document library by clicking on the link, i've to enter my credentials.
it's really bored and my colleguas doesn't have to do this, it opens the word directly.

We don't know which config put

Answer (score 0):

Follow tutorial to configure in browser:

https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/sharepoint/Automatic+Logins+-+Internet+Explorer

tell me if this resolved or no.

Thanks.